# Detection model for metallic elements

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I am new to image processing and learned only the basics from my studies.
I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible to create a CNN model to detect the scratches, pinholes, etc. in a metallic object?
2. Are there already any solution for it or does it need to be done manually for a desired project?
   The scratches can be so small that they are barely visible by human eye. So, will the CNN model be a right choice or will it need to much calculations for a computer to handle?
3. How to set proper lighting condition to reduce reflection and maybe flatten the object?

I am searching whole internet for any available solution. I've read multiple articles about this topic and finally decided that the only option is to use neural network, because the scratch sizes and positions can be infinity, so the hard-coded algorithm can be wrong in most situations.

As I said, I'm not experienced, but I have time to learn right now and it will be awesome to gain new experience and knowledge.

Hope someone has the idea what steps I need to take in order to get the desired effect.

Actually, I had just the sample code using Python and Opencv to preprocess the image, get the shape of the object and highlight the dark field on it. But it all depends on the proper lighting, so the pinholes are not exactly of the same color.

Below are the photo of my try to set the light properly.

[image: Unpolished material]

Comment: Please attach some reference images to show the scratches, pinholes that you are trying to detect.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/using-opencv-to-detect-unpolished-area-of-metalic-element/13759

Comment: I've updated the post with the photo.
I am trying to set the proper lightning as @ChristophRackwitz adviced me but it will be very difiicult, because the object has irregular shape, so can't find the right light set for detection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have multiple questions and you are a bit out of clue to decide from where to begin. I have narrowed down 3 questions which I'll try to answer one by one:

1. As Hissaan already mentioned, it is possible to create your own neural network to detect your object of interest. You would need to have a labelled dataset to train your model.
2. There are off-the-shelf object detectors such as [YOLO](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics), [MaskRCNN](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) etc. that you can use but they don't always work well for specific tasks. You would get better performance by fine-tuning them with your custom dataset. For starters, you can look at this implementation from [Roboflow](https://blog.roboflow.com/how-to-train-yolov8-on-a-custom-dataset/) on how to train a YOLOv8 using a custom dataset. This would get you some ideas for labelling your dataset and fine-tuning a pre-trained model. You can also check this [article](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2023/02/scratch-detection-using-mask-rcnn-yolov5/) which implements both MaskRCNN and YOLOv5 for a vehicle scratch detection project.
3. There is no single general technique to manipulate the light intensity in an image. You need to apply the techniques however it may seem fit for your problem. You can check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/changing-the-contrast-and-brightness-of-an-image-using-python-opencv/) to get a basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** this is totally **possible**. You can use image processing and machine learning models to do it.

Given the details you provided, I believe object detection model should be able to detect those objects. Since you didn't upload any sample images, I can not say for surety but tools like **yolov8** and **yolov5** are able to detect objects in images with just a handful of samples and they work pretty well.

Here's the Yolov8 github repo which explains the process of training the model and detecting objects really well. I believe anyone with average knowledge of python should be able to follow along: https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics

You can train it on a free colab gpu and run inferences(detections) on normal cpu device.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! 
I'll definetly check the proposed model.

Comment: if that solves you problem, don't forget to mark this as an accepted answer so that others could follow.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use a detail enhancing script/application to enhance the detail. In the following, I use a detail enhancing script using Imagemagick. Then I remove the background from the original to get a mask using Deep Learning/AI http://remove.bg. I then use the mask to merge the original and the detail enhanced versions so that the detail enhance part shows only for the object of interest (the pliers).

Input:

[image]

```
bash enhance6.sh pliers.jpg x.png
magick pliers-removebg-preview.png -alpha off -resize 1156x867! -threshold 50% mask.png
magick pliers.jpg x.png mask.png -compose over -composite pliers_detail.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thats really interesting solution, but the question is, can we now use some algorithm to detect this noisy pattern on natural structure of the object. Because in general the objects will most of the time have some noise or just single points at them. Your solution gave me more hope that maybe this project will not have to use deep learning

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/0x7UKTz
So I'm trying to find the right solution in python and Opencv, but the problem is how to separete the specific area of the image? Thresholding is not working, because the object is all shiny and there is more brighter areas than this one. 
I was also reading about Local Binary Pattern, but don't know if this can work if pattern can change.
You have any ideas how to highlight only this specific noisy area? 
Or it will be necessary to use some neural networks to train them to find the irregularities on the surface